# how to group/combine different value in one column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, powerbuilder

example:

```
date_entry  time_start  time_finished idle_code
8/8/2013    8:00        9:00             0
8/8/2013    9:01        10:00            1
8/8/2013    11:01       12:00            2 
8/8/2013    12:01       13:00            3
8/8/2013    13:01       14:00            4
8/8/2013    14:01       15:00            5
8/8/2013    16:01       17:00            6
8/8/2013    17:01       18:00            7
```

how can i combine/group the idle_code '0' and 6
then the other group idle_code '1','2','3','4','5','7'

i only need to groups group A = '0', '6' and group B = '1','2','3','4','5','7'

Comment: Too many sql dialects in your tags. Do you need tsql (so SQL Server), memsql or what?

Comment: im using powerbuilder 10.5 guys..

Comment: what would be your expected result ?

Comment: im expecting idle_code 0 and 6 to be group

Answer (score 0):

You may try grouping by by `case`, something like this:

```
  select ...
    from ...
   where ...
group by case 
           when (idle_code in ('0', '6')) then
             'A'
           else
             'B'
         end
```

P.S. I don't have PowerBuilder, so I've checked it on Oracle